# How and where to put Jquery into a fully PHP page?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have attempted to put my script into a page I have created but can't seem to get the script to work correctly. It is a paginate script which links to the "newsblocks" class. Where do I place the script to make it work?

```
<?php
/* 
Template Name: [Newspage]
*/ 
get_header();?>
<div id="main" class="defaultContentWidth">
 <div id="wrapper-row">
  <div id="primary">
    <div id="content">
    <?php the_breadcrumb();?>
        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title();?></h1>
        <?php if(have_posts()) :
            while(have_posts()) : the_post();?>
        <div class="newscont"><?php the_content();?></div>
            <?php endwhile;
        endif;?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/javascript/jquery.pajinate.js"></script>            
    <div class="contnewslist">
        <ul class="newsblocks">
        <li>
            <h2>NEWSLETTER 1</h2>
                    <i>November 01, 2014</i>
                    <p>This is the November edition of the newsletter for The Dry Cleaner App. Featuring in this newsletter is ...</p>
            <input type="submit" value="Download" id="submit" class="newsdownload">
        </li>
```

Comment: add js to your theme footer.php or in same page footer or where you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Optimizing the performance of a webpage it's always recommended to put the Javascript file to your footer.

So load your script files in your footer file.

In wordpress you've a `footer.php`

### Change

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/javascript/jquery.pajinate.js"></script>
```

### TO

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo echo get_template_directory(); ?>/javascript/jquery.pajinate.js"></script>
```

Comment: While this is true, I don't think that this is the reason the code's not working. I'm thinking that `blogInfo()` function returns a `string` but since he never `echo`ed it, it never gets printed..  ...But I never got around wordpress, I might be wrong.

Comment: <?php echo echo get_template_directory(); ?> ?

Comment: @Hoja.M.A I tried moving it to that file, and it made no difference, still not working. But thanks for the tip on optimisation!

Comment: @EliotE123. Check whether your file is in path : theme_folder/javascript/jquery.pajinate.js

Comment: @Hoja.M.A Yes, it is in that path at the moment.

Comment: Not a single one. What you suggested should 100% work? If yes, then perhaps the setup of the jquery is wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68870/discussion-between-hoja-m-a-and-eliote123).

Answer (score 1):

try to add js with `get_template_directory_uri()`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/javascript/jquery.pajinate.js"></script>
```

and add js to your theme **footer.php** or in same page footer or where you need

also i think typo here :- `jquery.pajinate.js` should be `jquery.paginate.js`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have changed it to that and it is still not working. Is there something wrong with the placement, or is it simply that my jquery is not working properly?

Comment: Yes, I have tried both of those and yet it doesn't seem to be working. And haha yes, it is not a typo, which is what I assumed at first!

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking `<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>` should be changed to `<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory');?>` but since you didn't gave us the definition of `bloginfo()` function we can't really do much..

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I believe it is something also to do with echo, but what you suggested has not worked.